# How to compare boolean index from firebase by ref()

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to store the game settings when the host of the match creates a new game. They have one chance to change the settings and then it'll lock.

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to get the index value (which should be either true or false) of the matchSettings/locked index from firebase.

The method works correctly, but I'd like to now stop the player from editing the settings after the first method call.

```
  changeSettings(time, increment) : void {
    let timePerRound = time;
    let decrease= increment;
    this.db.database.ref(`users/${this.gameId}/matchSettings/locked`).once('value').then( s => {
      if (s == true) {
        // dont allow another update
      }
    })
    this.db.object(`games/${this.gameId}/matchSettings`).update({
      timePerRound: time, decrease: increment, locked: true
    });
    console.log("game settings updated")
  }
```

**Here are some printscrns that show the database.**

http://prntscr.com/n0n9ef <--- data is not locked, therefore allow to change settings once.
http://prntscr.com/n0n9ov <--- I now called changeSettings(45,45) but it'll also change the locked to = true.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, one issue you're facing is that your first database reference is targeting `users`, whereas it should be targeting `games`. Besides that...

You should move the update call into the first result you receive from the database, so you know whether the update is allowed or not:

```
changeSettings(time, increment) : void {
    let timePerRound = time;
    let decrease= increment;

    this.db.database.ref(`games/${this.gameId}/matchSettings/locked`).once('value')
    .then( s => {
        if (s == true) {
            // dont allow another update
        } else {
            // Yes allow the update
            this.db.object(`games/${this.gameId}/matchSettings`).update({
                timePerRound: time, decrease: increment, locked: true
            });
            console.log("game settings updated")
        }
    })
}
```

Of course this code could be optimized, that's a fairly ugly if/else statement... but let's leave it basic for the sake of understanding.

Note that THIS IS NOT ENOUGH, not really. This is just front-end security... which is an illusion. If you really want to prevent game settings from changing, then you should implement [database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to that effect. For example, something like:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "games": {
            "$gameId": {
                "matchSettings": {
                    // Allow writing to this node only if...
                    // If the old data doesn't exist... (allow create attempts)
                    // Or if the old data's "locked" property is false
                    ".write": "!data.exists() || data.child('locked').val() == false"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer: Untested code & rules, for example only*